# asp.net mvc5 out of memory exception - sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, sitemap

I am building a personal project (MVC5) and now I am working on the sitemap.
I have this:

```
// GET: SiteMap
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServiceRepository servRepo = new ServiceRepository(db);
        BusinessRepository busRepo = new BusinessRepository(db);
        LocationRepository locRepo = new LocationRepository(db);
        CountryRepository countryRepo = new CountryRepository(db);

        SiteMapViewModel vm = new SiteMapViewModel();
        vm.Businesses = busRepo.GetAll().ToList();
        vm.Services = servRepo.GetAll().ToList();
        vm.Location = locRepo.GetAll().ToList();
        vm.Countries = countryRepo.GetAll().ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

I am getting out of memory exception, which does not surprise me. Each repo (table) has about 5 to 8 rows of data, except for Location, where I have postcodes of 4 countries, so roughly 100k records.
I tried Enumerable, instead of list with no luck. The View is just doing foreach loops based on the collections.
What would be the best way to generate the xml for all this content dynamically?
*Nuget package solutions will be my last option.

Comment: have you tried just removing the toList? If you don't need lists explicitly then you are wasting tons of memory doing this.

Comment: Hi Shoe, like I said in the question, " I tried Enumerable, instead of list with no luck."

Comment: Someone also told that a list of 100k rows should consume roughly 2MB of memory anyway. I have no idea if this is true or not

Comment: You should probably be working with IQueryable anyway. You should post the details of `GetAll`.

Comment: I am not in front of my pc now but the getAll is just an IQueryable on context.table

Comment: Note that assigning an IQueryable to an IEnumerable will cause all the results to fully buffer into memory rather than streaming

Comment: Ok, I will confirm tonight how my view model is created. I think that each list is actually a Enumerable type. I will change to IQueryable.

Comment: The other thing is: on my view, I have nested foreach loops. Could this be the reason? foreach(var country in vm.Countries) then inside, foreach(var location in vm.Location.Where(x => x.country == country.country), then inside another one: foreach(var service in vm.Services)

Comment: Not sure, I would breakpoint and debug to see exactly where the issue is.

Comment: breakpoint does not help. It runs for a while until it crashes. One more test I did was to .Take(10000), .Take(20000), when I did .Take(70000), that is when it crashed. The other point is, by using task manager, I can see IIS express consuming about 50% of processor and ram (iis again) increases from about 200MB to 1.1GB until it crashes. However I still have good gbRam available